# Kubernetes wont run after "make release"

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I downloaded Kubernetes and hit `make release`.

From the handbook thats all for installation. Unfortunately if I enter `kuberctl` linux tells me

> kuberctl: command not found

I downloaded kubernetes into `/root/kubernetes`. I noticed that there is a shell-script called kuberctl located in `/root/kubernetes/cluster`.

Unfortunately if I enter the directory `/root/kubernetes/cluster` and hit
`./kubectl.sh cluster-info` the script sais:

> /root/kubernetes/hack/lib/util.sh: line 226: kube::log::error: command not found

The corresponding line is

```
# looks for $1 in well-known output locations for the platform ($2)
# $KUBE_ROOT must be set
kube::util::find-binary-for-platform() {
  local -r lookfor="$1"
  local -r platform="$2"
  local locations=(
    "${KUBE_ROOT}/_output/bin/${lookfor}"
    "${KUBE_ROOT}/_output/dockerized/bin/${platform}/${lookfor}"
    "${KUBE_ROOT}/_output/local/bin/${platform}/${lookfor}"
    "${KUBE_ROOT}/platforms/${platform}/${lookfor}"
  )
  # if we're looking for the host platform, add local non-platform-qualified search paths
  if [[ "${platform}" = "$(kube::util::host_platform)" ]]; then
    locations+=(
      "${KUBE_ROOT}/_output/local/go/bin/${lookfor}"
      "${KUBE_ROOT}/_output/dockerized/go/bin/${lookfor}"
    );
  fi

  # List most recently-updated location.
  local -r bin=$( (ls -t "${locations[@]}" 2>/dev/null || true) | head -1 )

  if [[ -z "${bin}" ]]; then
    kube::log::error "Failed to find binary ${lookfor} for platform ${platform}"
    return 1
  fi

  echo -n "${bin}"
}
```

As the description of the method suggested I set the kubernetes-home by `export KUBE_HOME=/root/kubernetes/` but the err does not disappear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Intranet DMZ, :D

Comment: I am admittedly ignorant as to how to build this product.. but I have been building UNIX apps for 30 years now.  Have you tried `make install` ?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` Nice try

Comment: DOUGH!  I gave your question a point..

Comment: although there's no `install` rule in that makefile, the `release` one doesn't install anything, it finishes up creating a tarball => https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/build/release.sh . Look into your working directory `release-tar` subdir

Answer (score 0):

> `kuberctl: command not found`

The program is called `kubectl` and not `kube*r*ctl`.

Also

> As the description of the method suggested I set the kubernetes-home by `export KUBE_HOME=/root/kubernetes/` but the err does not disappear.

The snippet of code you pasted states you need the variable to be called `KUBE_ROOT` and not `KUBE_HOME`.